# increment in update query adds 2 in table instead of 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a news detail page where i am updating the 'views' field by 1 when the page is browsed. query is as followed:

```
$conn->query("update TABLE set views=views+1 where ID='$id'");
```

Its increment the value in db by 2. I am not able to understand this behavior.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is this query running inside a web page?

Comment: Please use prepared statements.

Comment: Check your web server log or use your browser dev tools to see if the web page is called twice.

Comment: Your query must be running twice. MySQL certainly handles this kind of query correctly. Is it possible you have a page with a redirect to another page, and both cause the query to run?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, you might be using PHP for the web development in your web page.

$con is the database connection object. By which you can run query.

**$con->query** is a PHP function will run the query that is passed into it. It works similar to that of the MYSQL terminal when you run the query.

When you run the following command

```
update TABLE set views=views+1 where ID='$id'
```

It will check for the **ID** which is equal to **$id** (For eg if $id = 2, then will check if id = 2) in your database table row and update the **views** column of that particular row by 1.

Make sure to check if the **view** column is **nullable** the better to update the query with the following

```
update TABLE set views=COALESCE(views, 0)+1 where ID='$id'
```

**COALESCE** is the built-in command of MYSQL which check if the **views** is **NULL** then get 0 and then updates with the count 1.